# ExtJs 4 - cross domain policy

Tags: cross-domain, extjs4, cross-domain-policy

I have a simple model:

```js
Ext.define('MovieModel', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [ {
            name : 'Title',
            mapping : '@title',
            type : 'string'
        } ],

        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'http://www.imdbapi.com/?r=xml&plot=full',
            method : 'GET',
            reader : {
                type : 'xml',
                record : 'movie'
            }
        }
    });
```

But this code doesn't support cross domain policy. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get rid of `r=xml` param. Instead of `ajax` proxy use `jsonp` one:

```js
    proxy : {
        type : 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://www.imdbapi.com/?plot=full',
        // jsonp uses its special method for retrieving data. So no need for the following row
        //method : 'GET',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            // the record param is used when data is nested construction
            // which is not true in your case
            //record : 'movie'
        }
    }
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/LSnda/).

Comment: @bontade, right. `callback=callback` is not needed. Updated my answer (check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/LSnda/)).