# Issue to get data from web api service using proxy in extjs store

Tags: javascript, web-services, extjs

When i try to use Web API service into my extjs application it gives me an error about **Invalid HTTP status code 500** . Can anyone tell me why it give me this error. My store code is like :

```
Ext.define(`Demo.store.Users`, {
    extend: `Ext.data.Store`,
    model: `Demo.model.User`,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: `rest`,
        url : `http://localhost:50893/Api/EmployeeService`,

        reader: {
            type: `json`
        }
    }

});
```

error :

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:50893/Api/EmployeeService?_dc=1388125117941&page=1&start=0&limit=25 500 (Internal Server Error) 
Ext.define.request Connection.js?_dc=1388125117581:358
Ext.define.doRequest Ajax.js?_dc=1388125117534:271
Ext.define.read Server.js?_dc=1388125117566:198
Ext.define.load AbstractStore.js?_dc=1388125117034:869
Base.implement.callParent ext-debug.js:4263
Ext.define.load Store.js?_dc=1388125117503:1552
(anonymous function) ext-debug.js:2085

OPTIONS http://localhost:50893/Api/EmployeeService?_dc=1388125117941&page=1&start=0&limit=25 Invalid HTTP status code 500 
Ext.define.request Connection.js?_dc=1388125117581:358
Ext.define.doRequest Ajax.js?_dc=1388125117534:271
Ext.define.read Server.js?_dc=1388125117566:198
Ext.define.load AbstractStore.js?_dc=1388125117034:869
Base.implement.callParent ext-debug.js:4263
Ext.define.load Store.js?_dc=1388125117503:1552
(anonymous function) ext-debug.js:2085

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50893/Api/EmployeeService?_dc=1388125117941&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Invalid HTTP status code 500
```

Thanks in advance
Sandy

Comment: 500 response code is an error on your back-end code

Comment: try executing your back-end code independently to validate it is in fact that code the problem, if it runs ok then it is the way you are calling the back-end method.

Comment: yeah it is working fine but when i add my web service reference then it gives me this error. Is any solution on it?? How do I get proper error message means i can understand where i am mistaken!!!!

Comment: Look for the log file of your application or application server. Where are you deploying the service?

Comment: no i am using self deployment. Web service is working fine in MVC application but only in extjs application i am getting 500 error.

Comment: What is the detail of your 500 error ? Null pointer exception? My guess is that you are trying to pass parameters that are not expected, but you should go to your log to see the details...

Comment: i posted my error after question asked. please refer that....

Comment: from where i can see log??? please tell me about it...

Comment: I'm not familiar with WCF but this might help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8275b410-67a2-4a4c-9458-844cba670e43/wcf-data-service-where-are-the-server-logs?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Comment: where are you getting the error lines from ? firebug ? For what I can see your ExtJs Store is just fine although you can validate it by creating a folder named data and creating a file named Employees.json then pointing your read config to that file and it should work.

Comment: And what is up with '<localhost>'? have you tried with 'localhost'?

Comment: No it is showing in chrome it give me above 3 errors.

Comment: i have tried this with web api service also..... it giving me same above errors in chrome.

Comment: when i try to upload question it give me error of localhost that's why i write in this style "<localhost>"

Comment: Mark localhost as code ... ok you've already done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solve my problem... it was cross domain issue instead of "rest" i use "jsonp" as request type. like :

```
Ext.define('CLG.store.Employee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'CLG.model.Employee',

        autoLoad: true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost:50893/Api/EmployeeService',

            reader: {
                type: 'json'

            }

        }


});
```

just see the link :
[ExtJs 4 - cross domain policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977730/extjs-4-cross-domain-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

Stores by default make requests using GET method therefore parameters are traveling through url change your store configuration to use method POST.

Inside proxy config put this:

```
actionMethods:{
    create: 'POST',
    read: 'POST',
    update: 'POST',
    destroy: 'POST'
}
```

Comment: no it's not working........ when proxy send request it send through "OPTIONS" method.

Comment: Hey!!! issue solve at last there was a cross domain request issue. so i just change my request type to jsonp and the error gone... :)... thanks dude for help me out !!

Comment: No prob. Post it as your own answer so other people can benefit.

Comment: but still i have one problem is that data not showing.... as i said before data from web api send in json format but  it's not sending object name with it.

Comment: [{"Id":2017,"FirstName":"abc","LastName":"abc","Designation":"Software Engineer","Salary":15000.0},{"Id":2018,"FirstName":"xyz","LastName":"xyz","Designation":"Student","Salary":15000.0}]

Comment: and i want data in format: {
    "success":true,
    "Employee":[
    {"FirstName":"abc","LastName":"abc","Designation":"Student","Salary":142.2},
{"FirstName":"xyz","LastName":"xyz","Designation":"Computer Operator","Salary":1423.41}
]
}